# How to join a table based on postcodes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, excel

I have 2 datasets, a shapefile with postcode polygons and an excel table (.xls) with postcodes and building count.

How to represent the excel table in the map?

I know that in ArcGIS it's possible to add a table and then do a spatial join but no idea how to do that on QGIS. Or even just use the geocoding option

I downloaded the spreadsheet plugin and did a join, but I still wonder if there would be a better way of doing this

Comment: Does your excel data contain any spatial data (e.g. coordinates, WKT etc.)? Note that you can either convert your .xls file to csv or use the **Spreadsheet Layers** plugin to import .xls files. If there are no spatial data then you can only join by matching fields from both the shapefile and the excel table. You can achieve this by right-clicking your shapefile and then: `Properties > Joins`; or from the _Processing Toolbox_: `QGIS geoalgorithms > Vector general tools > Join attributes table`.

Comment: No geometry, actually I solved my problem by getting Spreadsheet layers and joining by matching the postcode columns. Still I feel that if I didn't have allmighty expensive postcode data then I would be screwed.

Comment: Awesome, you should post your comment as an **answer**. Hope your postcode data wasn't too expensive =)